# Python optparse make_option() equivalent in argparse

Tags: python, argparse, optparse

From the OPTPARSE library reference:

```
option_list = [
    make_option("-f", "--filename",
                action="store", type="string", dest="filename"),
    make_option("-q", "--quiet",
                action="store_false", dest="verbose"),
    ]

parser = OptionParser(option_list=option_list)
```

---

Like the above example, I want to make a option list using make_option and pass it to a decorator which instantiates the parser and adds the arguments.

How can this be achieved in argparse? Is there a way to populate the parser other than parse_args()?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass it to a decorator".  I don't see any decorators here ... Also, I don't think that `parse_args` populates the parser.  `add_argument` populates the parser.

Comment: It is interesting that using `option_list` is deprecated, and that it is suggested to "use `add_option()` after creating the parser instead."  http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#creating-the-parser

Answer (score 2):

You can give `argparse.ArgumentParser` a list of [parent parsers](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#parents):

```
parent = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parent.add_argument('-f','--filename')
parent.add_argument('-q','--quiet',action='store_false',dest='verbose')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[parent])
...
namespace = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def process_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--filename', dest='filename', type=string, action='store')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = process_args()
```